# More Pythonic way to repeat some actions for a number of attributes

Tags: django, django-models, python

I have a Django app that allows the user to create variables and name them

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    int1_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    int1_default = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    int2_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    int2_default = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    float1_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    float1_default = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    float2_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    float2_default = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    string1_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    string1_default = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    string2_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    string2_default = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
```

And then they are stored

```
class ItemData(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, editable=False)
    int1_val = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    int2_val = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    float1_val = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    float2_val = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    string1_val = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    string2_val = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
```

And at the moment when I present the user with a form (that they have created) to fill in I do the following to lable up the fields with the names that user has given there variables

```
class ItemDataForm(ModelForm):

    # Only renames the fields based on whether the product has a name for the field
    def __init__(self,product,*args,**kwargs):
        super(ItemDataForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # delete all the fields that will be automatically filled in when saving
        del self.fields['created']
        # if the values is set in the product
        if product.int1_name:
            self.fields['int1_val'].label = product.int1_name
            self.fields['int1_val'].value = product.int1_default
        else:
            del self.fields['int1_val']
        if product.int2_name:
            self.fields['int2_val'].label = product.int2_name
            self.fields['int2_val'].value = product.int2_default
        else:
            del self.fields['int2_val']
        if product.float1_name:
            self.fields['float1_val'].label = product.float1_name
            self.fields['float1_val'].value = product.float1_default
        else:
            del self.fields['float1_val']
        if product.float2_name:
            self.fields['float2_val'].label = product.float2_name
            self.fields['float2_val'].value = product.float2_default
        else:
            del self.fields['float2_val']
        if product.string1_name:
            self.fields['string1_val'].label = product.string1_name
            self.fields['string1_val'].value = product.string1_default
        else:
            del self.fields['string1_val']
        if product.string2_name:
            self.fields['string2_val'].label = product.string2_name
            self.fields['string2_val'].value = product.string2_default
        else:
            del self.fields['string2_val']
```

Is there any way I could do this a bit more pythonicaly like have a list is `settings.py` and loop over it:

```
USER_SETTABLE_VARIABLES = ['int1','int2','float1','float2','string1','string2']
```

The same applies to the way I make sure that the data entered is unique before saving:

```
def is_unique(self,latestSI):
    if (self.cleaned_data['int1_val'] == latestSI.int1_val and
        self.cleaned_data['int2_val'] == latestSI.int2_val and
        self.cleaned_data['float1_val'] == latestSI.float1_val and
        self.cleaned_data['float2_val'] == latestSI.float2_val and
        self.cleaned_data['string1_val'] == latestSI.string1_val and
        self.cleaned_data['string2_val'] == latestSI.string2_val):
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

I only ask because when I want to add to the model I don't want to be editing all these functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use `exec` for this! `getattr` is perfectly adequate, much safer, and readable too.

```
class ItemDataForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,product,*args,**kwargs):
        super(ItemDataForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        del self.fields['created']
        fields = 'int1', 'int2', 'float1', 'float2', 'string1', 'string2'
        for field in fields:
            val = getattr(product, field + '_name')
            fval = field + '_val'
            if val:
                self.fields[fval].label = val
                self.fields[fval].value = getattr(product, field + '_default')
            else:
                del self.fields[fval]
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for `getaatr`. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

There maybe better ways but without adding any significant amount of code you can try this:

```
USER_SETTABLE_VARIABLES = ['int1','int2','float1','float2','string1','string2']

for variable in USER_SETTABLE_VARIABLES:
  exec("if if product."+variable+":\n\tself.fields['" + variable + "'].label = product."+variable+"\n\tself.fields['"+variable+"'].value = product."+variable+"\nelse:\n\tdel self.fields['"+variable+"']
```

But this only saves you the trouble of writing some code and makes it a wee bit easier to add some more user settable variabls. But I don't recommend this approach as your code will become less readable

Implement the same using getattr:

```
for variable in USER_SETTABLE_VARIABLES:
   if getattr(product, variable):
       self.fields[variable].label = getattr(product, variable):
       .....
   else:
       .....
```

Comment: @Sevenearths You absolutely don't need `exec` for this, just `getattr`.

Comment: What do you mean if `getattr` is implemented? If you use the `.` syntax, then you can use `getattr`. See my answer.